# Issue regarding add html data to web browser control repeatedly

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

This way i try to add html data to web browser control.

```
private void Adddata()
{
webBrowser1.DocumentText =
"<html><body>Please enter your name:<br/>" +
"<input type='text' name='userName'/><br/>" +
"<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>continue</a>" +
"</body></html>";
}
```

This works but when i call the `Adddata()` routine repeatedly then only first time data gets added but from the next time no data is getting added. i just want to add the data repeatedly. is there any way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText +=
```

But now when you can't add this code with many body and html tags.
Always build new String with one html and body tag.
Just append html code inside.

Comment: can u plzz tell me how can i remove any html element programmatically from web browser control. suppose by id name of that control. any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = //blah
```

to

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText += //blah
```

Well, not really. It wouldn't be the best of ideas to do that for html. What I would do is

```
//in class def
bool firstTime;
//in method
bool firstTimeLcl = firstTime
firstTime = false;
if (firstTimeLcl)
{
//write header
} 
else
{
String.Replace(/*closing tags*/, "");
}
//write everything within body
//write closing tags
```